# Modified heat eq. in 3D

Tags: pde

please how can I write gradient numerically?
I have an eq.
$\dfrac{\partial X}{\partial t}=\nabla^2 X + u\nabla X$
I wonder how write this in 3D.
Many thanks for any idea... I can find how to solve the "pure" heat eq. but so I don't know..

Comment: Hi lovis, and welcome to scicomp!  I presume $X$ is a scalar quantity, right?

Comment: yes, it is. Many thanks for your message. What can be done with this?

Comment: Excellent.  Are you using finite difference method to solve this equation as well?  What order accuracy do you expect your solution to have?

Comment: Do you only want to know how to discretize the gradient or how to solve the system? Can you rewrite your question to clarify?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your comments. I can find on the internet how to solve the 3D heat eq. but I would need to know how to do it with the gradient here. Would it be possible to do it in Fourier space? Then solve and go back? WOuld it help?

Comment: Your equation is called advection-diffusion equation. You may want to google for that.